# React high order funtion to insert random image not working when re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, rendering, lifecycle

I have a really simple HOC whose code is

```
import React from 'react';

const withRandomImage = Comp => props => {
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  return <Comp {...props} image={x} /> 
}

export default withRandomImage;
```

It works with an ImageBar component whose code is

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import withRandomImage from '../../hocs/WithRandomImage';

const Bar = styled.div`
    display: block;
    height: 310px;
    background-image: url(${props => props.image});
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
`

const formatWrapper = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "310px"
}

class ImageBar extends React.Component {

    getBgImage = () => {
        console.log(window.location.origin);
        return window.location.origin + '/hp/' + this.props.image + '.jpg';
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Image: ",this.getBgImage());
        return (
            <Bar className="ImageBar" image={this.getBgImage()}>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row align-items-center" style={formatWrapper}>
                        {this.props.inner}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Bar>
        )
    }
}

export default withRandomImage(ImageBar);
```

The idea is having a random image served as background image every time the page is refreshed. Images are served from `/hp/` folder inside React's `public` directory.

Everything works fine when the component is rendered for the first time. But inside this `ImageBar` I have some components (passed in `this.props.inner`) with event listeners attached to them. Every time an event id triggered the background image disappears.

This is an example of a component where this `ImageBar` is rendered.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <ImageBar inner={this.getSearchBar()} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I think this is something related to the components lifecycle, but can't figure exactly what is happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Whenever the props of a component changes, that will cause a rerender. I think react is smart enough that if you pass a children and render it directly, it will avoid to rerender (at least, I know that's the case for functional components). Could you check that? Like
`<ImageBar>{this.getSearchBar()}</ImageBar>` and then just render `{children}` in your ImageBar component?

Comment: Nice! I'll try that @Gonzalo.-

Comment: I did `<ImageBar><SearchBar></ImageBar>` and rendered {this.props.children). It worked up to a certain point. It renders the image, then it disappears instantly, without even waiting for something to be changed.

Comment: I also tried using `<ImageBar>{this.getSearchBar()}</ImageBar>` and got the same.

Comment: perhaps `math.random() * 26` is generating an url that does not have a proper image in your `hp` folder. Have you checked that? Keep in mind every render will generate a new random value, and a new prop. Try moving the generation of the image number outside of your returned enhanced component. Something like `const withRandomImage = Comp => {
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  return props => <Comp {...props} image={x} /> 
}`

Comment: It worked when I took the `const x` out of it! Would you please post it as an answer, so I may accept it? Thanks a lot, man! I was about to go crazy with this. Now I may peacefully go crazy with the rest of the thing in life! LOL

Comment: you're welcome. I posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `math.random() * 26` is generating an url that does not have a proper image in your `hp` folder. Have you checked that?

Keep in mind every render will generate a new random value, and a new prop. You can "freeze it" to the "first" generated value by moving out the generation of the number outside of your enhanced component.

Something along the lines of

```
const withRandomImage = Comp => {
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
    // when rereder occurs, only the code below will be run - so the image is always the same
    return props => <Comp {...props} image={x} />
}
```